# Need to replace a character in file2 with string in file1

Tags: shell, sed, awk

Here is what I am trying to do.

File1:

```
abc
bcd
cde
def
efg
fgh
ghi
```

File2:

```
ip:/vol0/scratch/&
ip:/vol0/sysbuild/
ip:/vol0/cde
ip:/vol0/mnt/cm/&
ip:/vol0/&
ip:/vol0/mnt/fgh
ip:/vol0/mnt/&
```

As you can see `File2` has `&` at the end of some lines, I need to replace the `&` with corresponding line in `File1` and ignore the lines without the  `&`  For example, if line 2 and line 3 doesn't have `&` the script would skip line 2 and 3 in both files and go to line 4 to replace the `&`

How would I achieve this with shell script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `paste` and `awk`:

```
$ paste file2 file1 | awk 'sub(/&\s+/,"")'
ip:/vol0/scratch/abc
ip:/vol0/mnt/cm/def
ip:/vol0/efg
ip:/vol0/mnt/ghi
```

---

Wasn't 100% clear if you wanted the lines not ending in `&` in the output:

```
$ paste file2 file1 | awk '{sub(/&\s+/,"");print $1}'
ip:/vol0/scratch/abc
ip:/vol0/sysbuild/
ip:/vol0/cde
ip:/vol0/mnt/cm/def
ip:/vol0/efg
ip:/vol0/mnt/fgh
ip:/vol0/mnt/ghi
```

With `sed`:

```
$ paste file2 file1 | sed -rn '/&/s/&\s+//p'
ip:/vol0/scratch/abc
ip:/vol0/mnt/cm/def
ip:/vol0/efg
ip:/vol0/mnt/ghi
```

Comment: don't want to have the `&` in the output.  Thanks

Comment: @sudo_O , is there only sed solution available without using paste. i want to see hoe to use multiple files with sed

Answer (score 0):

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[NR]=$0;next} sub(/&/,a[FNR])' file1 file2
```

Comment: The lines in File2 not containing `&` should be omitted from the output.

Comment: @user19340357 I've added a `sed` solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
paste file1 file2 | awk 'gsub( /&/, $1 )' | cut -f2-
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
awk '{if (NR == FNR){f[NR]= $0;}else {gsub("&",f[FNR],$0); print $0}}' file1.txt file2.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed = file1 | sed -r 'N;s/(.*)\n(.*)/\1s|\&$|\2|/' | sed -f - file2
```

1. `sed = file1` generate line numbers
2. `sed -r 'N;s/(.*)\n(.*)/\1s|\&$|\2|/'` combine line number with data line and produce a sed substitution command using the line number as an address.
3. `sed -f - file2` feed the above commands into a sed invocation using the `-f` switch and the standard input `-`